# Why there are no intended labels on this highcharter plot - R

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I have the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
hc <- structure(list(date_ref = c("2020-03-02", "2021-02-02", "2021-03-02"
), bracket_pay = c("T1", "T1", "T1"), col1 = c(10010, 12010, 11090), col2 = c(9850, 
11300, 10080), ratio = c(98.40, 94.09, 90.89)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

The data is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  date_ref   bracket_pay    col1    col2 ratio
  <chr>      <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-03-02 T1           10010.   9850.  98.4
2 2021-02-02 T1           12010.  11300.  94.1
3 2021-03-02 T1           11090.  10080.  90.9
```

I want to create a combined plot (column and line) using highcharter. This is what I tried:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(title = list(text = "Amount"),
         opposite = FALSE),
    list(title = list(text = "Percentage"),
         opposite = TRUE)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(hc, hcaes(x = date_ref, y = col2),
                yAxis = 0,
                name = "Amount",
                type = "column",
                color = "mediumseagreen") %>%
  hc_add_series(hc, hcaes(x = date_ref, y = ratio),
                yAxis = 1,
                name = "Advanced",
                type = "line",
                color = "tomato")
```

And the plot is almost good, however when you see the labels on the X axis, you see `1,2,3` instead of `2020-03-02,2021-02-02,2021-03-03`. By the way date_ref is a character vector. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The data provided says date_ref is a factor, not a character. That could be where the 1, 2, 3 is coming from if it's displaying the underlying numbers in the factor rather than the names. Is there a reason date_ref can't be in Date format (via `as.Date()`)? Even if it's in character rather than factor, I know that at least in ggplot character axes often cause problems.

Comment: I tried making `date_ref` as only characters but I still see `1,2,3` as the labels of each bar. If I format the variable `date_ref` as date, then the graphic is like that the months in between are absent. That's why I use that variable as character. By the way, thank you for your time in commenting this question.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what could explain that happening to a character vector unfortunately. Did you do `hc$date_ref <- as.character(hc$date_ref)` or something else?

Comment: Hi @Elle, I edited my question so now the dataset has `date_ref` as character. But even with that variable as character, I still see `1,2,3` as labels for each column in the X axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `hc_xAxis(type = 'category')` seems to fix it.

```
highchart() %>% 
hc_xAxis(type = 'category') %>%
hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(title = list(text = "Amount"),
         opposite = FALSE),
    list(title = list(text = "Percentage"),
         opposite = TRUE)) %>% 
hc_add_series(hc, hcaes(x = date_ref, y = col2),
              yAxis = 0,
              name = "Amount",
              type = "column",
              color = "mediumseagreen") %>%
hc_add_series(hc, hcaes(x = date_ref, y = ratio),
              yAxis = 1,
              name = "Advanced",
              type = "line",
              color = "tomato")
```

Comment: Everyday I learn something from people in Stackoverflow. Thank you very much @Elle, it worked fine!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!